# How to get rotation to work in iOS7?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, uikit, ios7

I want my app to support landscape only (left and right) on iPhone and iPad.
Hence in the info.plist I added landscape as the supported orientations.

My root controller is a UINavigationController with one controller on its stack.
However, my controller also rotates to portrait but not to portrait upside down.

If I Add `GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations()` (`supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:` in ObjC) to the app delegate and return landscape there, the rotation completely stops working.

How hard can it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. The topmost view controller has to return the interface orientations it wants to rotate to. In my case, that's the UINavigationController.
And the change was already in iOS6.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use?

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
```

hope this helps..

Comment: Like I wrote, that's what prevents rotation completely. See above.